# JSONDecoder with no output in Swift Playground

Tags: json, swift, swift-playground, jsondecoder

I am new to `Swift` `JSON`, so I am practicing in `Swift Playgrounds`. I'm pretty sure that this would be considered decoding a nested `JSON` key. But like I said, I'm new and I am not familiar with all of the technical terms.

Anyway, I thought that this code was right, but for some reason it won't print. And it's not showing me any error, which is making it harder to fix. But, I must be doing something wrong.

```
import UIKit

let jsonData :Data = """
{
"id": 1,
"name": "John Smith",
"username": "Johnny",
"email": "Johnny@yahoo.com",
"address": {
    "street": "Some Street",
    "suite": "100",
    "city": "SomeCity",
    "zipcode": "12345",
    }
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct User :Decodable {

    let id :Int
    let name :String
    let userName :String
    let email :String

    let street :String
    let suite :String
    let city :String
    let zipCode :String

    private enum UserKeys :String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case userName
        case email
        case address
    }

    private enum AddressKeys :String, CodingKey {

        case street
        case suite
        case city
        case zipCode

    }

    init(from decoder :Decoder) throws {

        let userContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: UserKeys.self)

        self.id = try userContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try userContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.userName = try userContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .userName)
        self.email = try userContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)

        let addressContainer = try userContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AddressKeys.self, forKey: .address)

        self.street = try addressContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .street)
        self.suite = try addressContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .suite)
        self.city = try addressContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
        self.zipCode = try addressContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .zipCode)

    }

}

if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: jsonData) {
    print(user.name)
    print(user.city)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `try/catch`  and print the error? That might help to isolate the problem.

Comment: This is an excellent idea presented by @Martin R in order to isolate problems with code that `Xcode` does not explicitly present to the programmer.

Comment: Playgrounds do this already. Just get rid of the `if let user = try?` and replace it with `let user = try`. It'll throw an error and that error will be shown in the console. No need to catch it or print it. (Xcode didn't used to do this, but it has for awhile now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `userName` and `zipCode` properties are camel-case as they should be following `Swift` standards. However, as what often happens with `JSON` data, the keys `"username"` and `"zipcode"` are both presented in lowercase. Fortunately, there is an easy fix for this. In your `private enums`, simply set both of the `properties` to their lowercase `stringValue` like this:

```
 case userName = "username"
 case zipCode = "zipcode"
```

Technically, I think that your dealing with a `nested dictionary` of `JSON properties`. I'm not sure though, maybe some of the experts on this site can elaborate more on that.

Comment: This worked. Now it prints correctly. So, I guess I only need to set those two properties because they are the only ones that aren't matching the lowercase JSON?